# How to wait for execution in other window in python

Tags: python, pyqt4, return-value

I have a program which will check for several conditions and check whether data is available or not. If there is any missing data then i will popup another window which will collect data in that window. It will have two buttons (Apply and Close). I want to return a value after button is triggered.

Both `program.py` and `dataEntry.py` have there own UIs designed in PyQt Disigner.

I want my program to wait for return value from other window. and depending on the input i will continue my other process.

Lets say program file is `program.py` and another window is `dataEntry.py` is imported in `program.py`

My `dataEntry.py` looks like

```
#imports necessary modules 

class dataEntry(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_DataEntry):

    def __init__(self):

        super(dataEntry,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Btn_Apply.clicked.connect(self.ApplyChanges)
        self.Btn_Close.clicked.connect(self.CancelChanges)

    def ApplyChanges(self):
        #This will trigger when ApplyButonn is clicked
        #I want to return True value from here
        return True

    def CancelChanges(self):
        #This will trigger when CancelButonn is clicked
        #I want to return False value from here
        return False
```

My `program.py` looks like

```
from dataEntry import dataEntry

class MainApp(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainApp):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainApp,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.CheckDetails()

    def CheckDetails(self):
        #Here i will check if required data is present else i will take data from dataEntry class

        if checkFails:

            input = dataEntry()
            input.show()

            #Here i want this class to wait until i get the result from dataEntry class
            EntryResult = return value from dataEntry

            if EntryResult:
                #Do some thing when its True    
             else:
                #Do some thing when its False
```

Comment: you should have provided the gui pys for both dataentry and program so that we can test before giving you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all import dataentry.py in program.py,
after this in your program.py

```
EntryResult = dataentry.py.Ui_DataEntry() #considering that the UI class in dataentry.py is Ui_DataEntry
```

This will run the dataentry.py and make your dataentry.py return the required value. This way, the program.py will wait till it gets a value from dataentry.py